# PayPal REST API cross reference transaction with payment

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I have managed to complete a PayPal payment using the REST PHP API. However, I want to know how to cross reference the REST transaction with the PayPal web user interface.

On the REST side I have payment id `(getID())` received before the transaction is approved. It looks like `'PAY-5BH83448XN85470XXXXXXXXXXX'`.

After the transaction is approved, I receive back at my redirect URL three other pieces of information:

```
- success=true
- token=EC-51Y92978Mxxxxxxxx
- PayerID=4Q7YVxxxxxxxx
```

When I log into PayPal and review the payment, none of these IDs match up with what is shown. The details for the payment show a Unique `Transaction ID` like `#4PP59868EXXXXXXXX` that does not match anything above.

How do I cross reference these different pieces of data?

Comment: Are you saying that the transaction id returned in the API response does not match the transaction id you see in payment transaction details in the payee's account?

Comment: The partial numbers I gave above are all from the same transaction. As you can see, none of them match. The PayPal account I reference above is the payee's account.

In my developers dashboard there is a transaction id of 3WK932105XXXXXXXX that matches the payment ID. I guess my real question is where do I find the transaction ID in the response. It is not obvious. As you can see, none of these ID's match.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I am having the same problem. Any information will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The response to the payment call will contain a list of transactions, which contains a set of related resources.  For a completed payment there will be a sale item, the id of the sale is the PayPal transaction id.

For ex (pseudo): payment.transactions[0].related_resources[sale].id

Sample here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/