# Get PayPal Unique Transaction ID, PayPal PHP API

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to get the Unique Transaction ID for PayPal payments. The payments are made in my android application and I capture the PAY-ID and store it in a database. I have a script that looks for new payments and grabs the PAY-ID and passes is to a PHP script that gets the payment information but for some reason it is not returning the unique transaction id. Here is what is being returned:

```
array (size=8)
  'id' => string 'PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=28)
  'create_time' => string '2014-03-13T20:51:07Z' (length=20)
  'update_time' => string '2014-03-13T20:51:10Z' (length=20)
  'state' => string 'approved' (length=8)
  'intent' => string 'sale' (length=4)
  'payer' => 
    array (size=2)
      'payment_method' => string 'paypal' (length=6)
      'payer_info' => 
        array (size=5)
          'email' => string 'someone@somewhere.com' (length=21)
          'first_name' => string 'my first name' (length=5)
          'last_name' => string 'my last name' (length=5)
          'payer_id' => string 'the payer id' (length=13)
          'shipping_address' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
  'transactions' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'amount' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          'description' => string 'INVOICE' (length=7)
          'related_resources' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  'links' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'href' => string 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  (length=71)
          'rel' => string 'self' (length=4)
          'method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
```

Now before we get to posting links and providing useless information let me inform you that I have already been all through the developer.paypal.com site and read extensivly through the PHP API. I have ran their sample, played with there scripts and manipulated it a bit, and have checked out every piece of code in their horrible and quite messy SDK. I have every thing working but would love to be able to get this unique id. Any suggestions? If you can, try keeping the solution in PHP.

On the developer site it shows that my response should like like this:(or similar which does contain the unique id.)

```
{
  "id": "PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
  "create_time": "2013-02-19T22:01:53Z",
  "update_time": "2013-02-19T22:01:55Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "type": "mastercard",
          "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx5559",
          "expire_month": "2",
          "expire_year": "2018",
          "first_name": "Betsy",
          "last_name": "Buyer"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "7.47"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "36C38912MN9658832",
            "create_time": "2013-02-19T22:01:53Z",
            "update_time": "2013-02-19T22:01:55Z",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "total": "7.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "parent_payment": "PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unique transaction ID for the sale should be right there in payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id, isn't it?  Or payment["transactions"][0]["related_resources"][0]["sale"]["id"] if it's a PHP object, yeah?  (That last statement is untested so take it with a grain of salt.)

You've deleted the contents of the related_resources array from your pseudo-vardump above, but as per the answer in [PayPal REST API cross reference transaction with payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736097/paypal-rest-api-cross-reference-transaction-with-payment) that's where it should be.  I mean, I have absolutely no idea why it's tucked away under 'related resources' for the transaction, but hey, that's PayPal for ya.

I just had this same problem (though I'm using the .NET REST API) and found my unique Transaction ID in that field; matches up exactly with the 'Transaction Details' page in their web admin.

Comment: Well, here is the funny thing, if I send  the PAY-ID to the PHP Script using Java and have the script echo print-r(payment->array()); I get the unique transaction id. If I just test in a web browser then I don't get it. I have tried 3 browsers. I have it working now but I am frustrated that it was working the whole time but just showing "some" of the request.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for PHP, just for the sake of others:

```
$payment->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
```

That worked for both, paypal payments (express-checkout) and cc transactions.